# Showing cell content on hint in DevExpress grid

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, devexpress, vcl, tcxgrid

I am using TcxGridDBTableView from DevExpress. Some of the cells contain really long strings, so I want to be able to show them to users using Hints. I want also to be able to do have line brakes in hint in places of semicolon in my text.

Do you know how to simply achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1TableView1Column3GetCellHint(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
  ACellViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; const AMousePos: TPoint;
  var AHintText: TCaption; var AIsHintMultiLine: Boolean;
  var AHintTextRect: TRect);
begin
  AHintText := VarToStr(ARecord.Values[Sender.Index]);
  AIsHintMultiLine := True;
end;
```

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B133087.aspx